# Are these scientific breakthroughs present in Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars

I just want to know if these technological breakthroughs have been realized in star wars.

1.) Genome technology to extend lifespans.

2.) Brain chips. putting a chip in your brain or wires to learn new information or abilities instantly.

3.) Living chips. Machines that can think.

Comment: This should be 3 separate questions

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, though they do not seem to be used in humans. Several alien species are referred to as genetically-engineering themselves for longevity, most notably the Yuuzhan Vong.
2. I don't know about "instantly," but Lobot, the bald character who works for Lando in *The Empire Strikes Back*, is a cyborg, or "borg-implanted human." It is mentioned in several *EU* sources, notably *The Black Fleet Crisis*, that he can search through computer networks like a non-implanted human would search their memories, picking out whatever knowledge he needs currently. He doesn't seem to able to do things like learning an entirely new language in a heartbeat, but he can access information far more quickly than having to learn it like a non-implant would.
3. You mean besides droids? There are several apparently sentient computer devices in the *EU*. IG-88, which was originally a droid but placed his consciousness in the Death Star's computer core, comes to mind immediately. A better example would be Flirt, a small computer-chip sized "droid" - she is referred to several times as a droid, but doesn't seem to match the descriptions of any other droids or droid-types in the entirety of *Star Wars* canon - which was designed to hack through security measures on computer devices, regardless of their size or duties. Several starship computers, notably *Hound's Tooth* and *Slave I*, also seem to be capable of independent action bordering on intelligent thought, if not crossing the line.